# Storing more than 8000 bytes in a column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, datatypes

I have a column in one of the tables in my SQL Server database that can have more than 8000 characters. As the maximum allowed character length for a column in SQL Server is 8000, how can I store the data which is having more than 8000 characters data?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are two things to consider if you want to store values > 8000 bytes in a single column in SQL Server.

First, the column must be capable of holding values of this length. For strings, this is typically done by giving the column a type of `varchar(max)` (for single-byte characters) or `nvarchar(max)` (for Unicode). As an example, the following table variable allows > 8000-byte strings in its column:

```
DECLARE @Example AS table
(
    LongColumn varchar(max) NULL
);
```

Second, you must ensure that any value you attempt to store in this column is also typed as e.g. `varchar(max)`. For example, the following results in truncation, because the constructed string is implicitly typed as varchar (not varchar(max)) and therefore limited to 8000 bytes:

```
DECLARE @Example AS table
(
    LongColumn varchar(max) NULL
);

INSERT @Example
    (LongColumn)
VALUES
    (REPLICATE('x', 9000)); -- 'x' is implicitly varchar

SELECT 
    E.LongColumn, 
    DATALENGTH(E.LongColumn)
FROM @Example AS E;
```

The following code works correctly because it constructs a string of type `varchar(max)`:

```
DECLARE @Example AS table
(
    LongColumn varchar(max) NULL
);

INSERT @Example
    (LongColumn)
VALUES
    (REPLICATE(CONVERT(varchar(max), 'x'), 9000));

SELECT 
    E.LongColumn, 
    DATALENGTH(E.LongColumn)
FROM @Example AS E;
```

See [char and varchar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-nz/library/ms176089.aspx) and [nchar and nvarchar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186939.aspx) in Books Online.